# Listing the novell rights using powershell

Tags: powershell, novell

I am doing a migration from novell to office 365, want I am wanting to do is to output the novell permissions/rights using powershell. So need the user/group and the permissions they have. Is this possible with get-acl or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Get-ACL does not list Novell File System Rights. Windows simply does not know the Novell (MicroFocus now) rights structure. You will need a third party tool. You can check CoolSolutions.

Maybe check:

https://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tools/bycategory/191.html